# Two comparators in one class

Tags: java, list, class, sorting, comparator

I have two Classes, both have int ID attribute, and I have to make this Comparator class twice in order to sort them by ID:

```
public class Class1Comparator implements Comparator<Class1> {

/**
 * Comparator Constructor.
 */
public Class1Comparator() {
}

@Override
public int compare(Class1 arg0, Class1 arg1) {
    return arg0.getId() - arg1.getId();
}
}
```

and the exact same one but Class2 instead of Class1, everything works, but is there a way to merge them in one class or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derive `Class1` and `Class2` from a base class, which contains the common ID, along with a single implementation of `Comparator<BaseClass>`.

Example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private int id;

    //.
    //.
    //.

    public static class CmpID implements Comparator<BaseClass>
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(BaseClass a, BaseClass b) {
            //Could be implemented null safe
            return a.id - b.id;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: You could also implement a common interface, e.g.

```
public interface IdentifiableObject
{
    int getId();
}
```

used by `Class1` and `Class2`.
Here too, a single implementation of `Comparator<IdentifiableObject>` would suffice.

Comment: this wouldn't be a good idea in my case, is there something else to do?

Comment: @codeoverflow: How are we meant to know what else would be reasonable if you won't say *why* Sam's idea doesn't work for you? For example, instead of using a base class you could use an interface... but again, maybe that isn't suitable in your case.

Comment: I tried for example to do implements Comparator<Class1>, Comparator<Class2>, but this doesn't work

Comment: This is a better idea with the IdentifiableObject, Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface GetId that defines that a class implementing it must have a getId() method. Have your classes implement the interface and then create a comparator that takes as its arguments any classes implementing that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Call the Comparatorclass different more general name, and change  to .
And this will allow you to use the same Comparator with different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no proper solution to your problem, because if you try to compare instances of two different classes it will result in ClassCastException because comparison can be done only between objects belonging to the same class. One solution could be to extend one class from another as [sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175253/sam) has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

- If the classes have a common ancestor, use that to fetch the ID and
  perform the comparison.
- Stretching it a bit - you could use reflection to get hold of the
  id attribute on each class. This solution will be slow and is not advisable.
- If there is no common ancestor and you do not control the code base, you are out of luck. You can of course stretch it even further and use dynamic proxies to emulate [duck typing in java](http://thinking-in-code.blogspot.in/2008/11/duck-typing-in-java-using-dynamic.html) but the ROI would be pretty slim :)